# How can I filter this with eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I try to filter SurveyQuestionnaire which have Answer = 'poor' and their Questionnaire have step = 'rating'.

I've tried to look through the documentation of Eloquent and I've found nothing help.

This is my models.

```
class Questionnaire extends Model {

...

    public function surveysQuestionnaires() {
        return $this->hasMany(SurveyQuestionnaire::class, 'question_id');
    }

    public function answers() {
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class, 'question_id');
    }

    public function questionnaires() {
        return $this->hasMany(QuestionnaireTranslation::class, 'question_id' );
    }

}

class SurveyQuestionnaire extends Model {


    public function survey() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Survey::class ,'survey_id');
    }

    public function questionnaires() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Questionnaire::class, 'question_id');
    }

    public function answer() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Answer::class, 'answer_id');
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you show your code where you're trying to get the results?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `hasMany` method returns query builder, so you can simply add some conditions:

```
public function surveysQuestionnaires() {
    return $this->hasMany(SurveyQuestionnaire::class, 'question_id')->where('Answer', 'poor');
}
```

Also, you can read this link [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships) and add your conditions manually after taking an instance of your model:

```
$items = App\Questionnaire::with(['surveysQuestionnaires' => function ($query) {
   $query->where('Answer', 'poor');
}])->get();
```